# C# Console Application Security

Tags: c#, security, console-application

i was just wondering, can a simple c# Console Application be detected by another program? and if that is possible can that other program read what is in the console or even know what functions are being used, etc (Since is all server side i dont think that's possible).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) you need to give a little more context here. What is the setup you have? You mention all is server side, but what is "all"? What is the purpose of this console application? In the digital world everything is possible, so yes a console application can be detected, but what are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Imagine a simple Console Application with just a "Console.WriteLine("Hello World")", my 2 main questions are. Can another program (installed on my PC) detect that a console application is running, and the 2nd is, Is there any way to another program  finds the "Hello World" written on the console. thks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trying to build an application that can do this or trying to figure out if you can prevent a malicious application from doing so, but to answer your slightly vague question: yes, it's possible.

On a .NET platform you could [get processes running on the local computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcesses), identify the console application among the processes and capture the [standard output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8) as it's being written to the console. Whether this applies to the scenario you have in mind is only a guess.